# How to partition hard disk with Windows 8 preinstalled?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I have just purchased my first Samsung NP550PC S03IN Laptop with 1TB HDD pre-installed with Windows 8.

Could anyone help me in partitioning my HDD without an external application? (I'm a beginner, so a step by step answer would be much appreciated)

Comment: Windows 8 has built-in tools that are very good. What are you trying to do exactly?  If it cannot do what your trying to do that means you need a third-party tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: [Step-By-Step: Partition Your Hard Drive | PCWorld](http://www.pcworld.com/article/73826/partition_your_hard_drive.html?page=2)

This should give the step by step instructions you need.

For a specific Windows 8 one try this: [Windows 8 disk management: extend, shrink, resize volume](http://www.partition-tool.com/resource/windows-8-partition-manager/windows-8-disk-management.htm)

Here are the steps as layed out on first link:

1. Check, optimize, and back up your drive(s)
   First, select Start, Programs, Accessories, System Tools, ScanDisk, click Thorough, and check the Automatically fix errors box. Then click Start.

   Next, defragment each drive by selecting Start, Programs, Accessories, System Tools, Disk Defragmenter.

   To use Windows 9 x's or Me's built-in backup utility, select Start, Programs, Accessories, System Tools, Backup and follow the directions. (If the utility isn't there, then for Windows 9 x, check Start, Settings, Control Panel, Add/Remove Programs, Windows Setup, Accessories, and for Windows Me, run Msbexp.exe from the Addons/MSBackup folder on the Me CD.) In Windows XP Professional, select Start, Control Panel, Performance and Maintenance, Back up your data.
2. Plan for partitions
   Before you run the partitioning software, decide how you want to organize your hard drive(s). Consider the size of the drive, whether you want to simply segregate data from the operating system and applications or create a more complex structure, and whether you want to run more than one OS. Read your partitioning software's manual for suggestions. Major partitioning utilities also have wizards that lead you through the process.
3. Run the software
   Once you've decided how to set up your partitions, follow the directions to install and run the partitioning software. Although the software won't let you make incorrect choices, you should check and double-check the new partitions to make sure you've allocated all the drive's space. Creating and moving partitions may take 30 minutes or more, depending on how full your drive is. The software will also format the new partitions for you.
4. Reboot and reorganize
   Once the partitions are created, reboot your PC to complete the process. You can then move your data around or install a new operating system. If you plan to store all your data in one of the new partitions, you'll have to tell your applications where to save files in the future. Usually, you can set this from the Preferences menu or File Locations tab in each application.
5. Problems?
   If you have problems accessing or using the new partitions, use the emergency disks that came with the partitioning software to double-check that the partitions were created and formatted. If they still don't work, then it's time to contact tech support.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm looking for Windows 8. The above link is for general one. Does the same applies for HDD preinstalled with Windows 8 as well?

Comment: well the partitions on a hard drive with windows 8 preinstalled shouldnt be any different than a hard drive with any other version of windows but the buttons may be slightly different. you just want to be sure you dont delete the partition that windows 8 is installed on or any recovery partitions you might have or it will erase it

Comment: for a specific windows 8 one try this: http://www.partition-tool.com/resource/windows-8-partition-manager/windows-8-disk-management.htm

Comment: Thanks so Much. It Helped me alot. Will try it and let u know!

Comment: Posting only links isn't considered a good answer. Please include the most important steps here on-site.

Comment: Sorry about that @slhck. Added the steps

Answer (score 1):

This one is short precise and to the point. Even a noob won't get lost.

http://www.vikitech.com/8438/windows-8-create-hard-drive-partition

Comment: Can you add some detail from the link? Straight links are not considered full/good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Best option would be to use some 3rd party software to make sure you wont corrupt your windows install, and to do all you want while system not booted. There is bootable cd/dvd for acronis suit, so you can burn it to flash drive and do whatever you want